# Question regarding subject-verb agreement

Tags: tense, subject-verb-agreement

Is the following statement correct:

> Presenting research at various forums and participating in numerous science fairs *have* introduced me to the world of research communication

Or is the italicised word 'has' instead?

Comment: It can be either. It depends on if you see *presenting* and *participating* as separate activities or if you see *presenting and participating* as a single activity with multiple facets.

Comment: I don't see any obvious connection between the two activities, so I would say the verb should be the plural "have".

Comment: I agree it _should_ be "have," but "has" _sounds_ better to my ear. There is too much distance between the two activities. If you simplify it as "Presenting and participating" then _have_ sounds better (and is still correct).